# Questions about Cobalt fonts

Tags: cobalt

1. I would like to use only English and Korean fonts to further reduce memory in Cobalt, but can I see where the font control is?
2. Are Indic languages not supported?

cobalt version - 11.78444

Comment: I strongly recommend you to not trim the fonts yourself, instead please pick one of the values for "cobalt_font_package" which your platform can afford. Even though your users may not speak other languages than English or Korean, they may still encounter emojis, text in other languages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Font files are located in https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/content/fonts/font_files/

When compiling Cobalt, font files are located in content/data/fonts directory of the output directory(ex: out/linux-x64x11_qa)

You can adjust font files from there or use system fonts. For more information, please refer https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/cobalt/content/fonts/README.md

2. YouTube Living Room app supports Indic locales like Gujarati(gu_IN), Hindi(hi_IN), Tamil(ta_IN), and etc.