# When Language is set on Korean，enter Youtube“Search”Page and input some character，character ghosting

Tags: cobalt

When Language is set on Korean for TV，enter Youtube “Search” Page and input some character，we found that character ghosting.As shown in image [Linux_TV.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb0V4.jpg). It is NG. It should be noted that only some combinations of characters will appear this phenomenon

[image: Linux_TV.jpg]

For comparison, I use a PC browser test.The result is shown in picture [PC.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmlWx.png). It is OK.

[image: PC.png]

From the picture PC.png we can see that when you enter some combination of characters, the top and bottom of different characters are not aligned.

Can you help to check it.

Comment: This looks more like a bug. Can you file it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=181120&template=699202, so that we can continue the discussion there?

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a Cobalt issue. Can you please work with your YouTube technical account manager with more details?
1. If this happens only with Cobalt or not.
2. Which fonts do you use.

Comment: We have consulted cobalt before, and the reply we got is that we should not use our own font. So fonts are cobalt own。The Question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150588/questions-about-cobalt-fonts

Comment: Can you help to cheek this issue?

Comment: This issus only happens  whih cobalt .We use other browsers did not find this problem.Instead of using local fonts, we use cobalt's own font.

Comment: TV we tested using OPENGL to display the youtube UI, so is there a way to dump the original content data  from cobalt to check whether it's right?

Comment: Let's follow up this from the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70829512